# VBA macro for Excel, can't make it work

Tags: excel, vba

I have to implement this code, but I'm not sure the syntax, I have problem with "ending an If sentence", first time that I've write a macro on VB.

Please any help to write this code well. I need to put the result of this in the Cell CK6:

(EDITED CODE)

```
Sub Funcion()
    Dim listo As Boolean
    Dim min As Integer
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim beta As Integer
    Dim tolerancia As Long
    Dim deficit As Long

    listo = False
    min = 0
    max = 1
    beta = 0
    tolerancia = 0.000001

    While listo = False
        prom = (min + mas) / 2
        deficit = Worksheets("ETR").Cells(6, "CI")

        If (deficit > 0) Then
            If (deficit < tolerancia) Then
                beta = prom
                listo = True
            Else: min = prom
            End If

        Else
            If (Abs(deficit) < tolerancia) Then
                beta = prom
                listo = True
            Else: max = prom
            End If
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Is there something wrong now? The macro get stucked but at least it show no errors.

Comment: `Cells(CI, 6)` should be `Cells(6, "CI")`, and you need an `End If` to close off the `If (deficit > 0) Then` - it looks like that should be just before the `End Sub`.  And it looks like you need a `Wend` after the newly inserted `End If`.

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to use `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code module.  That will then force you to do something about your variable `mas`.  (It is probably meant to be `max`.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try again

Comment: Re your edited code - see my second comment.

Comment: And I recommend that you step through your code line by line (press the F8 key to single-step) because, if ETR!CI6 is something like `0.1` (anything above `0.000001` or below `-0.000001`), you will get an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes! that's what I'm having now... when `ddeficit` becomes under 1 it get stucked. I've just open this question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571027/macro-on-vba-get-stucked-on-values-under-1