# Macro on VBA get stucked on values under 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro:

```
Sub SolverPaulo()

    Dim listo As Boolean
    Dim min As Single
    Dim max As Single
    Dim beta As Single
    Dim tolerancia As Single
    Dim deficit As Single
    Dim prom As Single

    listo = False
    min = 0
    max = 1
    beta = 0
    tolerancia = 0.1

    While listo = False
        prom = (min + max) / 2
        Cells(6, "CJ") = prom
        deficit = Cells(6, "CI")

        If (deficit > 0) Then
            If (deficit < tolerancia) Then
                beta = prom
                listo = True
            Else: min = prom
            End If

        Else
            If (Abs(deficit) < tolerancia) Then
                beta = prom
                listo = True
            Else: max = prom
            End If
        End If
    Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If I define `tolerancia = 1` or any value higher than 1 the macro works fine, but if I define values like `tolerancia = 0.1` or inferior under 1, the macro keeps working there in an infinite loop. I need to use `tolerancia = 0.00001`

I'm not sure of `Single` is a correct data type for the vars that I'm using, this is the first time that I work with VBA.

The idea is the macro should stop when `deficit` becomes minor than the `tolerancia`

At a certain point, the macro decide this:

```
If (0.33 < tolerancia)
```

There's when it crash... if `tolerancia` is actually minor than `0.33`. When I compare `tolerancia` with numbers higher than 1 there's no problem.

Now, in my Excel file, the configuration is in spanish, so the decimals are separated with `,` and not with `.` could be a reason that is failing on do that:

```
if (0,33 < 0.5)
```

comparing coma and point?

Any hint?

Comment: Try using `deficit = Cells(6, "CI").value2`. As far as I was aware VBA only uses the `.` for a decimal separator and doesn't do locale settings so even if the cell uses a comma separator vba will see it as a point separator. Using `.Value2` though strips out any formatting and just returns the underlying value of a `Range`

Comment: The comma used in your locale as a decimal separator will not be affecting things, unless the cell contains text that looks like a number, rather than an actual number.

Comment: Are you sure that your Excel formulas are set up so that, as you change CJ6, CI6 will converge to zero?  Try single-stepping through your code while also watching what values are being put into CJ6 and what is being calculated in CI6 based on the new value.

Comment: Yes, I will add a gif here showing how it's working. Its ok when `tolerancia`is 1 or higher. Look: https://i.imgur.com/e5fW4Jv.gif

Comment: When `deficit = 0,33`is not entering to `If (deficit > 0) Then`

Comment: Ok guys, I got it. `deficit`will no change anymore if is a `Single`data type, that's why get stucked in -0,32557734381407500000 plus, the Excel was considering only 4 decimals, so it tries to reach a `tolerancia` that will never reach

Comment: With doube it reach the value:  0,00136849842965603000 , and that's below than `tolerancia`so it stops. Finally!

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with floating point values it's best to use floating point when referencing a number, even as a literal, or the assumed data type will be the type entered as a literal.  0 = INT, 0.0 = FLOATING POINT.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was with the value type of the numbers, I had tu use Long, now it works, with Single the deficit would never reach the If case when listo is true (with tolerancia under 0.1). The code is:

```
Sub SolverPaulo()

    Dim listo As Boolean
    Dim min As Double
    Dim max As Double
    Dim beta As Double
    Dim tolerancia As Double
    Dim deficit As Double
    Dim prom As Double

    listo = False
    min = 0
    max = 1
    beta = 0
    tolerancia = 0.1

    While listo = False
        prom = (min + max) / 2
        Cells(6, "CJ") = prom
        deficit = Cells(6, "CI").Value2

        If (deficit > 0) Then
            If (deficit < tolerancia) Then
                beta = prom
                listo = True
            Else: min = prom
            End If

        Else
            If (Abs(deficit) < tolerancia) Then
                beta = prom
                listo = True
            Else: max = prom
            End If
        End If
    Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

A video working:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgxDK.gif